# Как сгенерировать и вернуть в response excel файл на Google App Engine (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Какой библиотекой сгенерировать файл excel из данных, выбираемых из базы и как его вернуть на запрос с клиента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я пользуюсь библиотекой **xlwt**. Она простая и имеет все базовые функции: создание страниц файла, запись в одну ячейку, объединение ячеек, а также наложение стилей и сохранение в буфер. Пример с отправкой XLS-файла в ответ на запрос в Google App Engine:

```
# необходимые библиотеки
# для сохранения
import StringIO
# для обработки таблиц
import xlwt
# для оформления ячеек
from xlwt import easyxf

...
# в каком-нибудь обработчике GET-запроса

# стиль для ячеек
usualStyle = easyxf('align: vert centre, horiz center')
# создание файла
workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="UTF-8")
# создание страницы
sh = workbook.add_sheet('CohortAnalysis')
# запись одной ячейки; аргумент стиля не обязателен
sh.write(row_number, column_number, "some value", usualStyle)
# запись в объединённую ячейку; можно добавить стиль
sh.write_merge(top_row, bottom_row, left_column, right_column "merged cells")

# сохранение в буфер и передача в ответ на запрос
out = StringIO.StringIO()
workbook.save(out)
filename = "table name"
filename = filename.encode('ascii')
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
self.response.headers.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".xls")
self.response.set_cookie("fileDownload", "true")
self.response.out.write(out.getvalue())
```

---

Полезное по **xlwt**:

- [Документация xlwt](http://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)
- [Скачать на PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt)
- [Материалы на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xlwt)

---

В Google App Engine по умолчанию такой библиотеки нет, её нужно устанавливать вручную в папку с проектом. [Здесь описание процесса на Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27).